# Export to Excel stopped working when I added an AJAX panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am just starting to learn how to use Ajax and I am stuck on this.

I have buttons in my ASP.net web site that work perfectly but the export to Excel and export to CSV stopped working after I added an Ajax panel.

They worked before I added the panel and when I debug the function `To_Excel_Click` is called is processed but it just does not create the Excel file. Something in Ajax I think is preventing the file to be created.

Thank you for any help

HTML Ajax

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <contenttemplate>
<asp:Button ID="BT1" runat="server" Text="Submit" Visible="false" onclick="BT1"/>
 <asp:Button ID="BT2" runat="server" Text="Submit" Visible="false" onclick="BT2" />
 <asp:Button ID="BTMakeCVS" runat="server" Text="Submit to CVS" Visible="false" onclick="BTMakeCVS_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="To_Excel" runat="server" Text="To Excel" onclick="To_Excel_Click" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True"/>
    </fieldset><fieldset class="Matainancefieldset3">
<asp:GridView ID="GVData" runat="server" Visible="false">
         <RowStyle CssClass="Row" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRow" /> 
    <PagerTemplate><table><tr><td>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server">
        </asp:PlaceHolder></td></tr></table>
    </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
 <asp:Label ID="LBExcell" runat="server" Text="Model:" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 </contenttemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

C#

```
protected void To_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ExcelExport.Export("Summary.xls", GVData);
}

public class ExcelExport
{
    public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
              "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                Table table = new Table();
                table.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

                if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    ExcelExport.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                }

                foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                {
                    ExcelExport.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                if (gv.FooterRow != null)
                {
                    ExcelExport.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
                }

                table.RenderControl(htw);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];

            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current
as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current
as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current
as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current
as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current
as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                ExcelExport.PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to the answer already given my Garrison... the `UpdatePanel` effectively uses the browser AJAX ability to request HTML updates from the server, and the the browser displays that HTML.  What you're effectively asking the server to do is return an Excel document as HTML to be displayed within the browser, which isn't going to work.  As he says, keep it outside of the panel and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do all that `Response` work with a `PartialPostBack` that the `UpdatePanel` fires.  If you're just rendering an already-rendered `GridView` w/ data to HTML so it can be saved as Excel, you're not really gaining anything by wrapping it in an `UpdatePanel`.

I'd put the Export to Excel button outside of the `UpdatePanel`, and that should avoid any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response this is very informative and is exactly what i need to know. it dose work out side of the panel and not in but i have also fund another way just in case some one is looking for the same thing                     http://forums.asp.net/t/1047851.aspx is a great page that shows you how to ajax to export to a file